# Running a CGI script from HTML

Tags: html, cgi

I have an HTML form like so:

`<form method="post" action="./cgi-bin/login.cgi">`

Clicking the submit button of this form should run the CGI file, but it displays the CGI file in the browser instead.
Here are the contents of login.cgi:

`#!/bin/sh
java Login`

This is all running on an Apache-Tomcat server.

What am I missing? Do I need to specifically configure the server to run CGI?

Comment: Apparently you did not configure your http server to interpret cgi scripts as such. So it treats the file as any ordinary file and delivers it, as requested.

Comment: @arkascha How do I configure my server to interpret CGI scripts?

Comment: Just read the documentation, as always with apache documentations it is excellent: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html Also a simple google search for "apache configure cgi" reveals many explanations. But the documentation should _always_ be the first spot you look into. It is the most precise and up to date source of information and certainly does not contain any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is probably not configured to run cgi scripts.

```
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
<Directory /path/to/cgi/files>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Also, Make sure that apache loading the cgi module in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

Comment: I am not familiar with configuring the server. Give me some time to figure it out, then I will try your suggestion. Thanks!